# How to pass zsh string without escaping # sign?

Tags: zsh

As title. I'm a user of zsh and I often read posts saying something like this:

```bash
nix profile install nixpkgs#hello
```

but I need to add quotes to the last argument to avoid this error:

```
zsh: no matches found: nixpkgs#hello
```

Is it possible to just use the command above instead of the one with `'nixpkgs#hello'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `setopt EXTENDED_GLOB` set, which causes the `#` character be used for filename generation (see [zshopts(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions) and [zshexpn(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn)).

You can disable this temporary in the shell by calling:

```
setopt NO_EXTENDED_GLOB
```

or permanently by removing it from wherever it is being added (I believe it is not set by default, so probably something is adding it, maybe your `.zshrc`).

Comment: Wow, I did set this option! In fact, I have forgotten why I need it.

Comment: Cool, I just found that I used to use this option to expand things like `*.(py|txt|json)`